# Update manager stuck in update

Tags: kernel, updates

The update manager is still stuck in updating the linux kernel (linux-image-2.6.35-24-generic) in the process of updating the grub entries. I think the problem is that the update manager doesn't have root privileges to continue (the app indicator with the key icon disappeared) and I want to know if it's safe to kill the update manager and start the process over.

Comment: I chose to end update manager after seeing this thread. After that I ran this comment in terminal `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. But I got the error "dpkg: status database area is locked by another process". Then I restarted the system after seeing a comment here. But it crashed GRUB (boot menu) on my syste and I had to go through a boot-repair via bootable OS on a pen-drive. So be careful when you kill update-manager.

Answer (score 6):

It is safe to kill update-manager, but after that please run the following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the first command, but it says: "dpkg: status database area is locked by another process"

Comment: @Harvey A simple restart might help you to get rid of **dpkg: status database area is locked by another process** If not then execute my commands in your terminal.It will help you.

Comment: were you able to resolve the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and found a solution that worked for me based on: [**linuxquestions.org**](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-open-11-resource-temporarily-unavailable-360554/)

Execute the following commands:

```
ps -e | grep apt
```

And then:

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

For each apt/aptd pid reported.